# running sudo -i command in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I was making setup script for me
where I have to run

```
sudo -i
```

then

```
echo 'blacklist r8188eu'|tee -a '/etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf'
```

When I use `sudo -i` it open's new terminal and terminate  my script that,s the proplem
I don't know if I can even use this `echo` on already open `sudo su`

I check some old query but most of them not related `sudo -i`

No problem related to passwd because running script in with `sudo`

I read there are some difference in `sudo su` and `sudo -i`
Then using `sudo -i` on already open terminal by `sudo su` wrong?

any help

Comment: After `sudo -i` and entering the password you can use `echo 'blacklist r8188eu' >> /etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf`.

Comment: @Cyrus how to use echo command  in terminal directly that's what your ans is for  if i m wrong then excuse me.

Comment: Sudo -i command opens a new terminal which terminate the my script that's actually

Comment: The `-i` option seems completely spurious here. If you want to script it, you don't want `-i`

Comment: `sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/realtek.conf <<<'blacklist r8188eu' >/dev/null`